# Raspberry Pi Python - Multicasting UDP using Socket not working on local network

Tags: python, sockets, networking, raspberry-pi, multicast

My current setup is this:

1. 1 x computer
2. 1 x GS308v2 ethernet HUB
3. 7 x raspberry pi's

The pi's are given static ip's ranging from 192.168.1.2 to 192.168.1.9. The dhcpcd.conf file is as follows:

[image]

The python script for sender:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import socket
import struct
import sys
import IN
import subprocess
import fcntl

MULTICAST_GROUP = '224.1.1.1'
MULTICAST_PORT = 12345

path = "-o /var/www/html/images-folder/pic.jpg"

SCMD = chr(1)
SEND = SCMD + path
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM, socket.IPPROTO_UDP)
dev = "eth0" + "\0"
sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, IN.SO_BINDTODEVICE, dev)
sock.setsockopt(socket.IPPROTO_IP, socket.IP_MULTICAST_TTL, 2)
sock.sendto(SEND, (MULTICAST_GROUP, MULTICAST_PORT))
sock.close()
```

The python for reciever:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import socket
import struct
import fcntl
from subprocess import call
import sys

MULTICAST_GROUP = '224.1.1.1'
MULTICAST_PORT = 12345

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM, socket.IPPROTO_UDP)

sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
sock.bind(('', MULTICAST_PORT))
req = struct.pack("4sl", socket.inet_aton(MULTICAST_GROUP), socket.INADDR_ANY)
sock.setsockopt(socket.IPPROTO_IP, socket.IP_ADD_MEMBERSHIP, req)

while True:
   data = sock.recv(10240)
```

This all works with dynamic ip's on a router. But is not working on the HUB with static ip's. The reciever script gives the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/dummyPi.py", line 17, in <module>
    sock.setsockopt(socket.IPPROTO_IP, socket.IP_ADD_MEMBERSHIP, req)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 228, in meth
    return getattr(self._sock,name)(*args)
socket.error: [Errno 19] No such device
```

How can this hub x pi network be configured to carry out this multicast?

Comment: It seems unlikely that you are using a hub; those are pretty rare. Do you mean a switch?

Comment: Nah I'm sure. It's a hub :P The equipment is old. The pi's are pi2, not 3, also

Comment: I just looked and the GS308 is a switch, not a hub. A switch may use IGMP snooping, which will only send multicast traffic for a group to an interface where a host has sent an IGMP join message for the group. You should look to see if that is the case, and try to send an IGMP join message from the receiver.

Comment: it's documentation mentions no IGMP at all. Sorry for the switch/hub confusion.

Comment: Is DNS necessary for UDP Multicast?

Comment: I have set static_router and static_dynamic_name_service arguments in dhcpcd.conf. Can they be causing the issue?

Comment: DNS really isn't necessary for multicast. You are also trying to use a Reserved multicast address. You should be using something in the Organization-Local scope (`239.0.0.0/8`). IGMP snooping is pretty much the default for switches because it keeps multicast from going where it is not wanted. IGMP is also key to being able to route multicast because it tells a multicast router that a host wants to receive traffic for that group. Multicast routing is _very_ different from regular unicast routing.

Comment: [This answer](https://serverfault.com/a/814296/324849) explains the importance of IGMP.

Comment: This gives me clue. Do we have to add routes to allow multicasting? I was not aware regarding this. Can you guide me?

Comment: Adding routes is for unicast routing. Multicast routing is very different. As the linked answer says, you need an add-on for Linux to route multicast traffic. You can search for that. PIM is pretty much the industry standard multicast routing protocol, but there are others. Multicast routing must be configured on every router in the path, which is why you cannot send multicast across the public Internet, except in tunnels that support multicast (not all do).

Answer (score 0):

The solution turned out to be that the routing for multicast also has to be setup for Linux if not using router. The following command saved me:

```
sudo ip route add 224.0.0.0/4 dev eth0
```

If someone would like to explain why this worked or what this command does exactly for the network, I'll be happy to learn. Feel free to comment.